# Building a document icon that changes its content with each page (HTML/CSS/Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

Users can visit pages where they can download a pdf document. Each document has its own page. Each document also has a specific name, page number, and author. Next to the download button I want to have an image of a document that changes its content depending on the document.

Sort of like this:

[image]

Except I want the title to change depending upon which document page is being viewed. The back end for this is completed, however, the front-end is more problematic.

Currently, I have a structure like this

```
<div class="container">
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div id="document">
        <p>$document->title</p>
        <p>$document->page_number</p>
        <p>$document->author</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div id="download-button">
        <button>Download</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

This displays a document image which changes its content depending on the page, next to the download button. However, I am wondering if there is a better way to do this? Currently the document image changes width with the page and doesn't retain a 'document' shape.

Thanks,

Comment: This is a very confusing question. I can advise you to post some code if you wish to get some help and probably edit your question.

Comment: I'm not rly sure, but maybe you are asking a CSS question and it has nothing to do with the whole document story? Is your question, how to make a box that doesn't change its width?